# Building "Tracking" module in OpenCV extra modules with Cmake does not generate relevant headers of that module

Tags: cmake, opencv3.1

I am not able to get a working custom build for implementation of some OpenCV sample motion tracking examples which requires the module "tracking" part of **opencv_contrib**. I tried to custom build on on VC12.0 x64 on windows. But it does not generate headers like **tracking.hpp** and **tracker.hpp** specific to tracking inside its own folder (C:\OpenCV\build\install\include\opencv2\tracking) like in the case of all other extra modules.

I followed the building procedure as [here](https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/)

My ultimate aim is to run the sample: tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.cpp found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build OpenCV 3.1 with tracking module by generating the solution for visual studio 2015 VC14 using CMake gui.
I followed the same procedure you provided in your question with two changes.

1. The tracking module has dependency with plot module (cmake told me that). So include plot module in the BUILD.
2. I built the entire solution in visual studio for both release and debug x64. Then I built the INSTALL project for both release and debug. After setting up environment variables and including libraries in VS I was able to run `tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.cpp`.